# How to add .jar files to javac compilation (Windows 10)

Tags: java, jar, compilation, apache-poi, javac

I am tryin to compile my java classes like this at the moment with javac

```
javac myClass.java
```

I am also using some .jar files (poi-3.15.jar...), which are necessary for classes such as Row, HSSFSheet and so on (for getting information from excel).
If I loaded these .jar files into Eclipse, I had no problem getting things working.

However, using the command prompt, my .jar files are not found.
I've put my .java files in the /src folder and .jar files to where my .classpath is. The compilation doesn't work.

Is it possible to place .java and .jar files into the same folder, successfully execute "javac" command and then execute the program.

I need to send my homework to a teacher, so the only thing he has to do is run the "javac myClass.java", following with "java myClass".

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered (a) consulting the tool documentation (b) using an IDE or (c) using a build tool such as Ant or Maven?

Answer (score 3):

To include jars, use:

```
javac -classpath "/path/to/jar1.jar;/parh/to/jar2.jar" MyClass.java
```

This will add jars to your classpath at compile time.